# The program works wrong. How do we catch error missage and direct it in a file error.txt? code that do not work

Tags: powershell

**The program works wrong. How do we catch error missage and direct it in a file error.txt?
code that do not work**

```
Get-content c:\attach\list.txt | Get-childitem -File | select -property fullname, length | Export-csv -notypeinformation -path C:\attach\error.txt
try {    
    $credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “aaa@dsf.ru”, (“sadf3e33” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) 
    Send-mailmessage -To "xx@company.com" -From "aaa@dsf.ru" -Encoding  ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -Subject "subject." -Body "Сообщение отправлено автоматически" -Smtpserver "mail.dsf.ru" -Port 25  -Attachments "C:\attach\test.txt" -Credential $credentials 
} catch {
    Write-Output "error sending email" $credentials
    Add-Content c:\attach\error.txt "error sending email"
}
```

wrong output in file error.txt   we cannot find record of error.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of things about your code.

- I completely do not understand what you are trying to achieve with the first line..
- You are using curly '*smart-quotes*' in code. Change these to straight ones
- Try to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for cmdlets that use many parameters like Send-MailMessage

In order to make the `try{..}catch{..}` work, you need to use the `-ErrorAction` parameter set to **Stop**.
This will have PowerShell treat all errors from the cmdlet as 'terminating errors' so they can be dealt with inside the `catch{..}` block.

Below ought to do what you want:

```
# Get an array of email addresses to use in the Bcc from a textfile
# Remove empty elements. Each email address should be on a separate line
$bcc = Get-Content -Path 'F:\MY\MyFiles\files\1DAY.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

try {
    $secPassword = "sadf3e33" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $credentials = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential "aaa@dsf.ru", $secPassword
    $mailParams  = @{
        'To'          = "xx@company.com"
        'Bcc'         = $bcc
        'From'        = "aaa@dsf.ru"
        'Encoding'    = 'UTF8'
        'Subject'     = "subject."
        'Body'        = "Сообщение отправлено автоматически"
        'Smtpserver'  = "mail.dsf.ru"
        'Port'        = 25
        'Attachments' = "C:\attach\test.txt"
        'Credential'  = $credentials 
    }
    # set ErrorAction to 'Stop' so all errors are regarded as terminating errors
    # and are dealed with in the catch block
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = "Error sending email: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Warning $errorMessage
    Add-Content -Path 'c:\attach\error.txt' -Value $errorMessage

}
```

Comment: how can i insert in $mailParams  = @{          the following      BCC (Get-Content F:\MY\MyFiles\files\1DAY.txt)

Comment: is it right   $mailParams  = @{
        'To'          = "xx@company.com"
        'Bcc'        = (Get-Content F:\MY\MyFiles\files\1DAY.txt)

Comment: @vitalyolegovich Yes, provided the file `F:\MY\MyFiles\files\1DAY.txt` is a list of email addresses each on a separate line. I have edited my answer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is to have a function created Write-Line that creates one line within a txt file with all the errors you catch.

Then in a try and catch block of code you could write the body of code,  and then create different catch functions for each error you have

```
catch{
        Write-Line(Exception e.Message)

}
```

Comment: you have to write a function that writes lines into a txt file and then is simply like that to write the line with error.

Comment: how can i insert in $mailParams = @{ the following BCC (Get-Content F:\MY\MyFiles\files\1DAY.txt)   ?